# How to filter objects by property on Wikidata using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I cannot find a way to filter objects by name. For example, this query should limit country objects to those with official name "Canada":

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?official_name WHERE {
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en,fr". }
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  ?country wdt:P1448 ?official_name.
  ?country wdt:P1448 "Canada".
}
LIMIT 100
```

[Here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fofficial_name%20WHERE%20%7B%0ASERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%2Cfr%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP1448%20%3Fofficial_name.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP1448%20%22Canada%22.%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20100) is a direct link to the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: missing language tag: `?country wdt:P1448 "Canada"@en.`

Comment: @AKSW: That indeed works and returns two rows. Do you know why `FILTER (?official_name="Canada"@en) ` and also `VALUES ?official_name {"Canada"}` do return only one entry (instead of the `?country wdt:P1448 "Canada"@en` line)?

Comment: @Cleb, names both in English and French are official. `"Canada"@en` is one of them, there is also `"Canada"@fr`.

Comment: And proabably you could use another property, not `P1448` due to data quality issues. The value of `P1488` [should be](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property_talk:P1448) in the original language of that region, however, see e. g. [Q159](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q159#P1448)

Comment: @StanislavKralin: How would one then get both of them without using the `@en` and `@fr` parts using `VALUES`?

Comment: @Cleb, `filter(str(?official_name) = "Canada")`?

Comment: @StanislavKralin: Yes, that works. Is there also an option using `VALUES`? This would work but then one has to specify the `@` part: `VALUES ?official_name {"Canada"@en "Canada"@fr}`.

Comment: @Cleb, `values (?official_name_str) {("Canada")} ... filter(str(?official_name)=?official_name_str)`?

Comment: @StanislavKralin: That works, thanks. Probably less efficient than just the `filter` version but was just curious from a technical point of view.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing how these things go, you'll likely be happier in the end with this somewhat fuzzy filter, than an exact match test... but you could change `filter ( contains (str(?official_name), "Canada") )` below to `filter ( str(?official_name) = "Canada")`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?country ?official_name WHERE {
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en,fr". }
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  ?country wdt:P1448 ?official_name.
# ?country wdt:P1448 "Canada".
  filter ( contains (str(?official_name), "Canada") )
}
LIMIT 100
```